# New to coding trying to learn JS and node . . . do I need an IDE or will Sails.js do it all?

Tags: node.js, ide, text-editor, sails.js

I'm completely new to coding and I'm wondering if I will need an IDE or text editor if I'm using something like Sails.js (a real time MVC framework) in the attempt to build a node app. It seems like the IDE/text editor functionality is built into Sails.js.  For more on Sails (http://www.sailsjs.org/#/).

Btw, I'm not looking to grow into a CTO but rather I'm a DiY entrepreneur that wants to build an MVP and go about building a team or raising money with prototype in hand. I care nothing for learning great practice or fundamentals of programming besides what's pragmatic for the express goal of building an MVP as I have no interest in being a career programmer.  Having said that, I'd like my MVP to work and I don't want to do something dumb either.

Thank you for the guidance!

Comment: Sails is an MVC framework. Why do you think that means you don't have to write any code?

Comment: I think I need to write code. It just seems like I can write code in the framework based on the video I saw. Seriously, I'm learning from scratch as I go with no one but Stack Overflow, books and the net to help. It's little things like this that unravel copious amounts of time. What would be helpful is an explanation of how these things are different and fit together.

Comment: I'm sorry if this simple question is too much for the community to handle but I was under the impression that this was the place to get questions answered. I'm trying to get started with ZERO prior knowledge of coding and I know I have some pretty lame questions but with no one to go to, I was hoping that I could come here to get some of the basics elaborated upon so that I could get started.

Comment: Btw, I took out the time to do quite a few searches in stack overflow and on the net to get this question answered. There was nothing on it. I'm seriously learning JS but there are a bunch of things that are not quite intutitive. Moreover, given my dearth of experience "framework" doesn't actually mean anything to me yet as I have yet to use one.

Answer (score 1):

Sails is a web framework. You will need some kind of text editor in order to write code to handle each request. I suggest you start a level up and learn the basics of what a language is and how it plays into building an app before you select a framework or runtime.

Something like http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript can get you started.

Comment: Thanks! This helps somewhat. I'm mostly through the CodeAcademy JS tutorial. I guess frameworks plug into the IDE/text editor somehow?